# Unknown Error for rich text editor Laravel Trix

Tags: php, laravel, rich-text-editor, web-development-server, trix

I am new in Laravel, and I face this problem through
Is there any problem? I try to fix this many time but it still not work can someone help me, thank you in advance.

TermsAndPolicycontroller

```
 public function store()
    {
        TermsAndPolicy::create([
            'termsandpolicy-trixFields' => request('termsandpolicy-trixFields'),
        ]);

        return redirect('/');

    }
```

model: TermAndPolicy

```
namespace App\Models;
use Te7aHoudini\LaravelTrix\Traits\HasTrixRichText;


class TermsAndPolicy
{
    use HasTrixRichText;

    protected $guarded = [];

}
```

my view:

```
<header>@trixassets</header>
@section('content')
    <div class="card b-t-green">
        <div class="card-body">
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('terms_and_policy.store') }}">
                @csrf
                @trix(\App\TermsAndPolicy::class, 'content',  [ 'hideTools' => ['file-tools'] ])
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
<header>@trixassets</header>

<input type="submit">
```

**change to**

```
<head>@trixassets</head>

<button class="" type="submit">submit</button>
```

Your code:

```
return redirect('/');
```

u can using route, exam:

```
return redirect()->route('discussions.index');
```